# Issue with having both slow fall and levitation

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make Blaze armor: I have a command block giving me levitation 253, essentially slow falling while wearing. However, I would like to change the amplifier to 1 (so the player floats up) temporarily as long as the player is holding a blaze rod. But the two commands do not seem to mix; the amplifier of 1 won't overwrite the 255.

Here's what I have now:

If wearing the Blaze armor: `/effect @p 25 3600 253 true`

If holding the Blaze rod: `/effect @p 25 3600 1 true`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you applying these effects? Some variety of `/execute` command?

Comment: If you have a new question, ask it separately. If you are prevented from asking any more questions, *please* wait until you can do so again.

Comment: [Please don't add (solved) to your question's title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116101/566903)

Comment: Then how do i delete it? I tried to but it was undeleted several times.

Comment: You don't; questions on Stack Exchange websites are not solely intended to help the asker, but instead to help future visitors. Deleting this question would accomplish nothing other than making Arqade an objectively worse source of information.

Comment: Literally no one helped me, I had to figure it out myself. Its better off removed but whatever,.

Comment: So [post whatever you figured out as an answer](/help/self-answer), so future visitors can benefit from your solution.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer, not an edit to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to make Blaze armor but no one helped so I figured it out myself. While wearing the gear, I had one command block giving me levitation 253, (essentially slow falling while wearing) then while holding a blaze rod, I had to remove the amplifier and add and new amplifier of 1 (so the player floats up). The amplifier of 1 won't overwrite the 255, so you have to remove the 255 and add a completely new effect.

If wearing the Blaze armor: `/effect @p 25 3600 253 true`

If holding the Blaze rod: `/effect @p 25 3600 1 true`

Answer (score 2):

This is intended, only stronger effects overwrite weaker ones. You need to clear the stronger one if you want to instantly apply the weaker one.

Also, your command syntax is wrong in the question, but probably not in the game (otherwise you would have gotten an error message). Please copy-paste your commands in the future, instead of manually re-typing them, because errors like this can happen then.

Comment: @Aceplante Dude, stop. You will not get your edit through just by trying often enough. Various people have clearly decided that your edit does not help and you have not even commented about why you're even try to do that.

Comment: As I said in the suggestions, he claims my syntax is wrong which is not accurate. Maybe leave the first half of the comment, but not the second.

Comment: That's because you edited the question to include totally different commands! Of course that would invalidate existing answers, that's why that is forbidden here. Please read [tour] and [help] so that you at least know the rules here. I also see a lot of edits in the revision history that shouldn't have been done. When a moderator rolls back your edit, you should think about why that was done and definitely not keep doing the same mistake again.

Comment: Never once did I edit the commands. Im on 1.12 and he gave me 1.13 commands and claimed my syntax was wrong, which is why it needs to be fixed.